# Importing XML to Java - What advantages are there to use JAXB over custom-reading the file?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I easily found JAXB for importing XML into Java code, however, after looking at it a bit more, I started wondering if it were more than I really needed.

It should be rather simple XML that I or other users would create.
For example:

```
<Type>Armor Material</Type> //could be various types of parent objects
<Name>Steel</Name>              //object properties
<Toughness>10</Toughness>

<Type>Armor Material</Type>
<Name>Iron</Name>
<Toughness>7</Toughness>
```

For the background on my problem: I have a game written in Java, and aim to have many Objects of certain types defined in the XML. I'm hoping to keep the XML as simple as possible for easy user-modding.

I know how to read from a file for creating my own custom solution - but I have never dealt with marshalling/unmarshalling and JAXB in general. I won't lie - something about it intimidates me, maybe because it seems like this "black box" which I don't quite understand.

Are there clear advantages to argue *for* learning how to get it work, as opposed to implementing a solution I already know I can get to work?

Comment: It is an *opinion* on which I should do for my case, but that is not what I am asking. There should be unbiased advantages for using JAXB - that is what I am asking about.

Answer (score 1):

You definitely want to use JAXB.

Whether your XML is simple or complex, write an XML schema (xsd) file. You want the schema file anyway, so you can validate the files you are reading. Use xjc (part of JAXB) to generate Java classes for all the element of your XML schema (complete with setters/getters). Then, it is a one-liner to read or write an XML file.

Because the XML file is mapped to/from Java objects, it is very easy to manipulate these data structures (to create or consume them) in Java.

JAXB is a plugin architecture and there are quite a few open source plugins that you can utilize to enhance the generated classes. By default, JAXB generates all your setters/getters automatically, but there are plugins that will generate equals/hashcode, fluent-style methods, clone, etc. There is even a plugin (hyperjaxb3) that will put JPA annotations on the generated classes, so you can go XML->Java->database->Java->XML all based on the XML schema.

I have worked on projects that used JAXB to generate POJOs even though we didn't need XML - it was quicker to write and easier to maintain the XML schema than all the Java code for the POJOs.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Java 8, perhaps a dynamic style would be a good fit

```
XmlDynamic xml = new XmlDynamic(
    "<items>" +
        "<item>" +
            "<type>Armor Material</type>" +
            "<name>Steel</name>" +
            "<toughness>10</toughness>" +
        "</item>" +
        "<item>" +
            "<type>Armor Material</type>" +
            "<name>Iron</name>" +
            "<toughness>7</toughness>" +
        "</item>" +
    "</items>"
);

xml.get("items|item|name").asString(); // "Steel"
xml.get("items|item[1]|toughness").convert().intoInteger(); // 7
```

see https://github.com/alexheretic/dynamics#xml-dynamics